# AS2 Attached movie clip over everything

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, cs4

I'm having trouble in as2, I'm using

```
var ThisMC:MovieClip = this.AttachMovieClip("Duck"+rnd_Duck + "_mc", "target" +        _global.cDepth, _global.CDepth)
```

This Action is on the Actions layer, first frame bottom of timeline, yet the ducks still appear on the top, how might I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

the keyword **this** means you are attaching it to the stage.  make an empty container movieClip, and attachMovie into that:

```
var ThisMC:MovieClip = myContainerMovieClip.attachMovie("Duck"+rnd_Duck + "_mc", "target" +        _global.cDepth, _global.CDepth)
```

Now you can place this container movieclip on any layer you wish and your "Duck" will be where you expect.